# Python NLTK difference between a sentiment and an incident

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Hi i want to implement a system which can identify whether the given sentence is an incident or a sentiment.

I was going through python NLTK and found out that there is a way to find out positivity or negativity of a sentense.

Found out the ref link: [ref link](http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/)

I want to achieve like
My new Phone is not as good as I expected should be treated as sentiment 
and Camera of my phone is not working should be considered as incident.

I gave a Idea of making my own clusters for training my system for finding  out such but not getting  a desired solution is there a built-in way to find that or any idea on how can be approach for solution of same.

Advance thanks for your time.

Comment: In semantic/sentiment annotations, there are two polarity and neutral. Train your system using three classes instead of two and anything that falls under neutral would be a superset of "incident" and you have to further learn to abstract incident from sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, or can construct, a corpus of appropriately categorized sentences, you could use it to train a classifier. There can be as many categories as you need (two, three or more).

You'll have to do some work (reading and experimenting) to find the best features to use for the task. I'd start by POS-tagging the sentence so you can pull out the verb(s), etc. Take a look at the NLTK book's chapter on [classifiers](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html).

Use proper training/testing methodology (always test on data that was not seen during training), and make sure you have enough training data-- it's easy to "overtrain" your classifier so that it does well on the training data, by using characteristics that coincidentally correlate with the category but will not recur in novel data.